# How to lock my application for n mintues after n times of wrong credentials

Tags: android

i want to lock my application for n minutes after x times of login failure
, locking is supposed to be working after restarting application

any suggestions?

Comment: store the time, where you want to unlock the app in shared preferences, and then each time your app is launched - check if current time is > then saved time

Comment: What about storing this information on the server site and returning one of HTTP error codes when the user tries to log in again before the lock time passes?

Comment: The important part if first to store the time and then show the error dialog or make the UI changes. Otherwise an attacker can kill your app before writing the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler handler;
//Write in OnCreate
 handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Perform Here as you want.
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        startHandler();

 @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        stopHandler();//stop first and then start
        startHandler();
    }

    public void stopHandler() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    public void startHandler() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5 * 60 * 1000); //for 5 minutes
    }
```